# Deploying django at sub url using nginx

Tags: django, nginx

Is it possible to deploy Django at sub_url without modifying urls like this:

```
url = script_name + url
```

I want to deploy one app at abc.com/one and another at abc.com/two.

I was able to do it but when I click any url, it is pointing to abc.com/link but not abc.com/one/link.

So, want to know if its some Django thing or nginx thing.

Nginx code:

```
server {
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 10M;
keepalive_timeout    15;
server_name localhost test.com;

location /one/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;

    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /one;

}
location /two/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002/;

    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /two;

}

location /static {

    root /home/path/test;
}
}
```

The above code running site but as I said, when I click on any links, it is pointing to /link but not /one/link.

Comment: What kind of Django production server do you use? uwsgi/gunicorn/something else? Could you post your current nginx config?

Comment: your django app runs on every url you want it to you dont need to provide any domain specific settings in your django app. can you provide additional information whats in your nginx conf for these urls since this is most likely the reason for your current behaviour from my point of view.

Comment: Sure, I will provide.

Comment: You can't do it without editing every link in your HTML code

Comment: Technically, it would be much easier to implement this by running these two apps on different subdomains: `one.abc.com` and `two.abc.com`, but I'm not sure this is a suitable solution for your needs